# Separate and Create iterative variable from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, iteration

I have this string:

> `number = "0123456789"`

I want to create variables that are iterative having values from the string.
For example,

I want a string like

```
a1 =1, 
a3=3,
... 
a8=8
```

Please advise.
Thank You

Comment: why only a1, a3 and a8? why not other variables like a2, a4, a5, a6, a7 ,a9?

Comment: I think he was giving an example. @HarshaBiyani :)

Comment: ok,, then please modify your question..

Comment: While this can be done - are you sure you really want to do it? Usually, you would use a list for this kind of thing (like `a = [i for i in range(10)]`).

Answer (score 1):

There is ambiguity in question. I address the following part: 'I want to create variables that are iterative having values from the string.'

If you solve problem of creating variables dynamically you have created a new problem - how to access them dynamically. Therefore it's much better to use some built-in datastrucuture like list, tuple or dictionary.

Keeping this in mind answer to the question:

```
number = '0123456789'   

for num in number:                                  
    globals()[f'a{num}'] = int(num)
```

This code will create variables a0, a1...a9 with corresponding integer values.

Comment: Thank You for the assumptions. I am learning Python and hence the ambiguity. But what you provided as a solution, works for me. Thank You

Comment: I still strongly advise against creating variables this way. You are much better off with list/tuple/dictionary and accessing associated values with indices or keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an iterator function - namely `iter()`

For example:

```
number = '0123456789'
iterator = iter(number)
```

Then, with `next()`, we can do something like this:

```
next(iterator)
'0'
next(iterator)
'1'
```

That is, you can use the next function to obtain the next value.

Answer (score 0):

To make an iterable object with indecies I do something like:

```
number = "0123456789"
new_number = ""
for i in number:
    if i != number[-1]:
        new_number += i + " "
    else:
        new_number += i
iterable = new_number.split(" ")
```

This could likely be made less messy if you are interested in that, but this does the trick. Note: the elements in the iterable will be strings.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
res = ', '.join(['a{}={}'.format(i,i) for i in number])
```

output

```
'a0=0, a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4, a5=5, a6=6, a7=7, a8=8, a9=9'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each character in your variable number but you have to typecast it to string. And please note that `number=0123456789` will error in Python. You need a string value. So typecasting the numeric value to string will solve it.

Example:

```
number = str(123456789)
for i in number:
    globals() ['a'+i] = int(i)
```

Then you can use the created variable as usual like this:

```
print(a1)
print(a9)
```

This will output:

```
1
9
```

I hope this answered your question.